# How to expose a constexpr to Cython?

Tags: python, c++, cython

A file `Globals.h` contains the following definition of a constant:

```
namespace MyNameSpace {

/** Constants **/
constexpr index none = std::numeric_limits<index>::max();

}
```

... where `index` is a typedef for `uint64_t`.

How can I expose it to Cython and Python?

A failed attempt:

```
cdef extern from "../cpp/Globals.h" namespace "MyNamespace":
    cdef index _none "MyNamespace::none"

none = _none
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for exposing (global) constants is similar to the [syntax for exposing simple attributes](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#add-public-attributes) and the [syntax for exposing static members](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#static-member-method), in your example the syntax is almost right except that you need to omit the `cdef` statement, the `cdef` statement is only for declaring new variables in Cython, not for adding information about externally declared variables.

```
cdef extern from "../cpp/Globals.h" namespace "MyNamespace":
    index _none "MyNamespace::none"

none = _none
```

Then you can use `none` in Python, if your Cython module is named `mymodule`, the import statement could be

```
from mymodule import none
```

if you want to make `none` available as global name in your Python code.