# How to expose static constexpr from cython

Tags: python, c++, static, cython, constexpr

I need to wrap the following demo example from cpp to cython for using in Python

```
class Foo1 : public MFoo<unsigned int> { 
public:
    constexpr Foo1(unsigned int val) : MFoo{val} {}
    }
};

class Foo{
public:
    static constexpr Foo1 any {0};
    static constexpr Foo1 one {1<<1};
    static constexpr Foo1 two {1<<2};
};
```

This is what I currently have 
file.pxd

```
cdef extern from "../MFoo.hpp":
    cdef cppclass MFoo:
        pass

cdef extern from "../header.hpp":
    cdef cppclass Foo1(MFoo):
        pass

cdef extern from "../header.hpp":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        ###@staticmethod
        Foo1 _any "Foo::any"
        Foo1 _one "Foo::one"
        Foo1 _two "Foo::two"
###any=_any
### I also need to link my cpp definitions of any,one and two 
###to cython file but I am facing Error:Python object cannot be declared extern
```

My file.pyx

```
def Bar(self,PyFoo1 abc)
    return file.Bar(######) # how would I call something like Foo::one
```

I need to know how to wrap this in cython. I am using [How to expose a constexpr to Cython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181964/how-to-expose-a-constexpr-to-cython)
which is similar but still not very useful

Comment: I think the issue is using static member variables, rather than `constexpr`. You definitely can't apply the `staticmethod` decorator to them though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is that Cython doesn't provide a way to express C++ static member variables. To solve this you can put them at the global scope and use strings to ensure that the correct C++ code is generated. The `constexpr` is irrelevant - Cython doesn't need to know about it.

I've created a minimal example that's slightly simplified from yours (it omits the irrelevant template class that you don't provide a definition for, for example):

```
class C {
public:
    constexpr C(unsigned int) {}
};

class D {
public:
    static constexpr C any {0};
    static constexpr C one {1<<1};
    static constexpr C two {1<<2};
};

inline void bar(const C&) {}
```

and in cython:

```
cdef extern from "whatever.hpp":
    cdef cppclass C:
        pass
    cdef cppclass D:
        pass
    C any "D::any"
    C one "D::one"
    C two "D::two"

    void bar(const C&)
```

Notice that I don't put `any`, `one` and `two` inside `D`, but ensure that the strings create C++ code `D::any` etc.

---

I think there's a second question about how to call `bar` from Python. There's obviously a number of options but an easy way would be to pass a string, and have a Cython function that matches the string to the C++ value:

```
# except NULL allows Cython to signal an error to the calling function
cdef const C* get_C_instance(s) except NULL:
    if s=="any":
        return &any
    elif s=="one":
        return &one
    elif s=="two":
        return &two
    raise ValueError("Unrecognised string {0}".format(s))

def py_bar(s):
    return bar(get_C_instance(s)[0])
```

This isn't the only solution for creating a Python interface - you could create a wrapper class that holds a `C` and have instances of it called `any`, `one`, `two` for example.